How to move content to another site in SharePoint online
I have few SharePoint sites that were created, each of them having few news posts and some documents.
We now are consolidating our SharePoint sites and those sites should now be combined in one unique one.
To move the documents, it is not that difficult, I can download all in one go, then upload to the other site with a couple of drag and drops.
But for the news entries and pages, it is another story.
How can we move the news entries to the consolidation site? What are the issues I should expect (dead links,...)?

One of the things you can use, is PowerAutomate to copy pages:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0dVGt7wZTs
Have also a look here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/move-copy-sharepoint-pages-from-one-site-to-another-in-classic/m-p/2544668

Another option, very good for List Items, Documents, but a bit more complicated is Powershell script.
For this checkout the PnP Module: https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Copy-PnPFile.html
As for the issues, yes, you can expect dead links, but maybe SharePoint redirect can help with this:

As part of changing a SharePoint site address, moving a site to a
different geo location, or swapping a site, we automatically create
redirects to ensure that links pointing to the prior URL continue to
work. These redirects are sites that use a special site template at
the prior site URL.
For example, if you changed a site address from
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/OldSiteName to
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/NewSiteName or moved a site from
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName to
https://contosoEUR.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName, we'll place a
redirect (Template type REDIRECTSITE#0) at the old URL, which contains
special headers and logic to redirect your browser requests to the new
site.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-site-redirects
